# ASP.NET Core 6 Create data in the database with swagger

Tags: asp.net-core-6.0

As it says in the title, I want to save data in the database by entering the data in the swagger, for this I made a service layer and controller and in the backend is the model and in frontend the dto.

Service Class

```
 public async Task<SuperHeroDto> Create(SuperHeroDto dto)
    {
        #region
        _firstAPIDatabaseContext.SuperHeroes.Add(dto); 
        var saveChangesAsync= await  _firstAPIDatabaseContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        
    }
```

I have the problem here:
_firstAPIDatabaseContext.SuperHeroes.Add(dto);

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Iuw0.png)

I want to learn it on my own, but need tips on how to do it.
I also created a profile for folders

Comment: Thanks I solved the problem. I created a variable and wrote the model in there (entity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the difference between **SuperHeroDto** and **SuperHero** in your code.

But obviously the code you provided is wrong to store SuperHeroDto objects in SuperHeroes.

Maybe you can write

```
_firstAPIDatabaseContext.SuperHeroeDto.Add(dto);
```

Comment: Yup, u are right. There should be a conversion between the dto and the db entity if he wants to save it to DB.

Comment: Thanks I solved the problem. I created a variable and wrote the model in there (entity)